# Using sed to remove new line characters from the middle of a field

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, cat

the data i have looks something like this

```
a,b,c,d
a,b1
b2,c,d
A,B,C,D
```

What is happening is that in field 2 there is occasionally a new line character in the second field so the line gets split over two lines

So far i have found a sed script that will do this it reads like

```
cat file| sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\(\(b1\)\)\n/\1/g'
```

but i am struggling to get the correct combinations of (.*,) to make this work so i've substituted it with b1 to get this example to work but in the real world A, B, C and D are field of mixed length and content

The end result i'm looking for is this

```
a,b,c,d
a,b1b2,c,d
A.B,C,D
```

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks
Matt

Comment: is awk ok? seems more like awk to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have here a solution that is not yet perfect - but I will further think about it. If your version of `sed` supports extended regular expressions you could do:

```
cat file | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/((^|\n)([^,]+,){0,2}[^,]+)\n/\1/g'
```

That will work if there's a line break in one of the first three columns. Up to now it does not yet work with multiple line breaks in a "line".

*Explanation:*
`(^|\n)` matches the beginning of the line (resp. a line break)
`[^,]+,` means: at least one (`+` means one ore more) character!="," followed by a ","
`([^,]+,){0,2}` matches if there are 0-2 columns delimited with a ","
The `[^,]+` means that there are some (at least one) character!="," following the 0-2 columns.
The trailing `\n` matches a line break

Summarized the `s` command will match all lines containing 0-3 columns with a line break at the end and will substitute it with itself (`\1`) excluding the trailing line break.

Comment: thanks very much this works well for one line break although i must admit i don't really understand the code!!!

Comment: @matt1234: I will add an explanation.

Comment: Why use cat when you needn't cat? `sed -r '...' < file` is shorter to type and costs one less process.

Comment: @Benoit: You are right. But I just did it as the OP did. Actually you even could do `sed -r '...' file` without stdin redirection.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. The only difference in my case is that the delimiter is a "|" and the column with the issue is the 10th column in my csv. No errors, `sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/((^|\n)([^|]+|){0,11}[^|]+)\n/\1/g' test.csv` simply returns the contents of test.csv without any changes.

Comment: @JimWalker: You have to escape the "|" because it has a special meaning in regular expressions: `sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/((^|\n)([^|]+\|){0,11}[^|]+)\n/\1/g'`

Answer (score 1):

In awk

```
awk -F, 'NF < 4 {getline nextline; $0 = $0 nextline} 1' filename
```